# "not to" end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> You’re not limited to using it. (It’s preferable not to.) There are
>   other options already defined.

Can you explain me the "not to" structure? "It’s preferable not to" means "It’s not preferable" ?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you do not understand, and what exactly you need to know, please?

Comment: "It’s preferable not to" means "It’s not preferable" ? @WS2

Comment: No. *It is preferable not to* means it is preferable not to do whatever it was you were thinking of doing. And saying *It is preferable not to (swim)*, is quite different to saying *It is not preferable to (swim).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the infinitive marker 'to' appears without an infinite verb (which was elided), the antecedent verb is the previous one (in this case 'using'; ie, 'to use').  The 'not' negates 'to use', not 'preferable', so 'it is preferable not to' means 'it is preferable to not use it'.

Comment: like saying of hamlet, to be or to not be